# Login with google to Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, adfs

I am new to a team that is using Dynamics CRM as the backend of a product offering. Currently, they have a difficult set-up that requires for all clients of the product to have a user in the company AD domain. Obviously, this is not very sustainable. What I would like to do is permit a user to login using a Google account (or other) and authenticate using ADFS to gain access.

It appears this is possible but I am completely new to this world with dynamics and ADFS and am not sure how to go about even searching for tutorials or sample implementations.

**Added detail to address licensing concerns:**

Each user would still have their own account in Dynamics. However, we would like the identity provider to be something other than Active Directory.

Comment: Dynamics CRM licensing in prohibits you from allowing multiple users to use a service account to login to the same account.

Comment: Added some detail to explain.